# Drawing beyond a UIView's bounds

Tags: ios, uiview, core-graphics, drawrect

I'm trying to draw a complex border around a UIView in it's drawRect method using core graphics. The border is being clipped because it's outside of the view's bounds. Is there any way to prevent this clipping? Setting clipsToBounds to NO doesn't work.

Comment: @MichaelDeluca, what the heck is the connection between the auto-layout and the `CoreGraphics`? the context has a specific size and it is not possible to draw over the bounds of the context.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`drawRect:` gives you a `CGRect`. This defines the area in which you can draw. As it stands, you cannot draw outside this area.

You'd have to look into a different solution to your problem. I'd suggest `CALayer`s, or a subview/superview hierarchy, perhaps a border view and a content view. But don't try doing that in `drawRect:`, unless you can get the desired results while keeping within the area specified by `drawRect:`.